# Rails app rake db:migrate aborted - syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems, rake, gemfile

I keep getting the following error when running rake db:migrate:

```
rake aborted!
syntax error on line 18, col 9: `   adapter: mysql'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is my database.yml file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
    adapter: mysql
    database: DATABASENAME
    username: USERNAME
    password: PASSWORD
```

If I remove the production settings to try and rectify the issue in my development environment, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- openid/store/filesystem

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Which I believe is caused by some sort of gem dependancy problem, so here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.0'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-ext'
gem 'devise'
gem "configatron"
gem "post_commit"
gem 'will_paginate', '> 3.0'
gem "configatron"
gem "declarative_authorization"
gem "aasm"
gem "gravatar_image_tag"
gem "polish"
gem "simple_form"
gem "i18n_generators"
gem "i18n_routing"
gem "delayed_job"
gem "oauth2"
gem "fb_graph"
gem "omniauth"
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4"
gem "meta_search"

group :development do
  # To use debugger
  # gem 'ruby-debug'
  # gem 'ruby-debug19' if you are using ruby 1.9.2 or higher
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => "sqlite3"
  gem "nifty-generators"
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'mysql'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
group :test do
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
gem "mocha", :group => :test
```

I can't work out why A) It's not accepting the production info and B) why I keep getting the no such file to load error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tabbing is different.

[Whitespace indentation is used to denote structure; however tab characters are never allowed as indentation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Syntax)

Try the following:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: DATABASENAME
  username: USERNAME
  password: PASSWORD
```

Comment: Well spotted, I'm still getting the 'no such file to load -- openid/store/filesystem' error though.

Comment: Try running `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: There looks like there'll be a lot of back and forth to solve this, I set up a chat for this question.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6591/rails-app-rake-dbmigrate-aborted-syntax-error